# Has anyone tried playing a Fanned Fret guitar/bass? How did it feel vs standard? Did you stick with it?

Tags: guitar, fingering, bass-guitar, fretboard

The title says it all. I'm intrigued by fanned frets, but buying an instrument like that is a big leap. If you've tried it, I'd like to hear about your experience.

Comment: Sorry, gear recommendations aren't [covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and neither are "[everybody share your thoughts](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" sorts of questions. Feel free to ask in the chat room; you need 20 reputation to join, but that's as easy as two upvotes. Meanwhile, this could maybe be edited into an on-topic question, like "What technique changes are needed when switching" or something like that.

Comment: @AndyBonner It is not really a gear recommendation, but as it stands it is not a well phrased question. "Has anyone tried playing a Fanned Fret guitar/bass?" Well, probably. I’m quite sure the OP could generalize this to a good question about benefits and differences of fanned frets, and what situations these a well suited for. And then I think this might very well be suited for this site.